# jQuery/Javascript Default Choices for Dropdown in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I have the following side-by-side question in Qualtrics.

[Picture of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgZcy.jpg)

The dropdown menu in has the same four statements as presented in the Statement Choices and 'Dummy Column'. I am trying to get the default choice for the dropdown to be the value in the 'Dummy Column'.

Using the following code, I can get the dropdown value to equal the Statement Choice column:

```
// Default Choice
var $embedded = [];
var $length = $jq(".SBS2 select").length;
for (var i=0;i<$length-1;i++)
{
$embedded[i] = $jq(".Choice .c1").eq(i).text().trim();
$jq(".SBS2 select").eq(i).find('option:contains(' +$embedded[i]+ ')').attr('selected','selected');
}

$jq('.SBS1').hide(); / Hide Dummy Column/
```

I am struggling to update the code to pick up the value in 'Dummy Column' instead. I have tried updating ".Choice .c1" to ".SBS1 input" but it just selects the last value in the dropdown list for all rows.

Can someone help with what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:
1. Your values are in text input fields, so you need to get the values of those fields.
2. Your selector needs to find the text input fields, so '.SBS1 input' is correct.

Thus, change your `$embedded[i] =` line of code to this:

```
$embedded[i] = $jq(".SBS1 input").eq(i).val().trim();
```

It seems you are doing it the hard way though. Why not just pipe your default values into the $embedded array to being with instead of creating a dummy  column that you then have to hide?

```
var $embedded = ["${e://Field/ed1}".trim(), "${e://Field/ed2}".trim(), etc. ]
```

You could then delete the `$embedded[i] =` line altogether.

P.S. This isn't PHP where you need $ in front of variables...it actually makes it a bit confusing at first glance. Also, no need to assign jQuery to a variable, just use `jQuery`.